# Getting different results from the loop combination (for first 3 runs)

Tags: python, loops

I wrote a code that include some loops. My purpose is to draw a diagram according to a list. So, assume that a list like (2,4) (2,8) (4,8). The diagram takes the values as a target. 8 is divisible by both 4 and 2. But in the diagram, you can not draw a line both 2->4 and 2->8. So, (2,8) must be removed from the list for making just one way to 8.
Example;

(a,b)-(b,e)>(a,e)

(b,d)-(d,f)>(b,f)

(c,e)-(e,g)>(cg)

(a,d)-(d,f)>(a,f)

I wrote the code but the problem is my code gives different results for first 3 runs.

```
list2 = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 9), (4, 4), (4, 8), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
edge_list = list2
for x,y in edge_list:
    if x == y:
        edge_list.remove((x,y))
for a, b in edge_list:
    if a!=b:
        for z in edges[b]:
            if (z!=a) and (z%a==0):
                if (a,b) in edge_list:
                    edge_list.remove((a,b))
print(edge_list)
```

Comment: `edges` is not defined.

Comment: Hi trgtulas, not sure what are you trying to get here. Could you clarify further?

Comment: How do you want to create an edge between two numbers? if `first%second =0`?
And after that you want to remove extra edges?

Comment: edges = {9: [3, 1],  8: [4, 2, 1],  7: [1],  6: [3, 2, 1],  5: [1],  4: [2, 1],  3: [1],  2: [1]}.   It is a dictionary that shows the divisiblity of the numbers in list. There is nine values. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9